# using another's class methods without inheritance (python)

Tags: python, inheritance

Say I have the following

```
class ClassA (object):
  def meth1() ..

class ClassB (ClassA):
 def meth1() ..
 def meth2() ..
 def meth3() .. 

class ClassC (ClassB): 
 calls meth2() and meth(3)
```

I am trying to refactor ClassC to make it inherit from ClassA instead. However, ClassC uses two important methods from ClassB that I don't want to rewrite, they have to stay under ClassB. Also, I don't want meth1 in ClassA to be overwritten by ClassB.
Is there a way to call meth2 and meth3 from ClassB in ClassC and make ClassC inherit ClassA and use meth1 from ClassA? 
I hope my explanation is clear. And I'd appreciate it if you direct me to some documentation about this.

Comment: It's not really clear; could you give a less abstract [mcve]? Note that Python does support multiple inheritance, although that's not always the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Make `ClassC` a subclass of *both* `ClassA` and `ClassB`:

```
class ClassC (ClassA, ClassB): 
   #calls meth2() and meth3()
```

`ClassC().meth1()` will call ClassA's `meth1`, while `ClassC().meth2()` and `ClassC().meth3()` would call `ClassB`'s methods, since methods not defined in `ClassC` are [looked-up in the base classes in order](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance).

The order in which bases classes are searched is governed by the  method resolution order (MRO). For more on MRO see [Michele Simionato's article](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) and [Shalabh Chaturvedi's article](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#method-resolution-order).

Comment: Thank you so much! so to make sure I understand, the method calls in ClassC will first look for the method definition in ClassC, then ClassA, then ClassB right?

Answer (score 0):

If the methods absolutely NEED to stay under their original classes, I would probably go with multiple inheritance, though I would likely need more information on the specifics of the project to say so definitely.

```
class ClassC(ClassA, ClassB):
           ... code here ...
```